# Retain position of element in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array of objects that I am displaying in an HTML page using the ng-repeat directive. Each item when clicked opens a new html page. Whenever I click on any item, it takes me to the new page and when I click back, it repositions me to the top of the page (on the first item).

What is the best way to retain the position of the item, such that when the user clicks on the item, goes the new page and clicks back then he/she is taken to the same element that triggered the action.

A demo would be preferable.

Thank you!

Comment: What is "page" in your example? Is it "view" in Angular? Is it a different endpoint URL? Also, if a "demo is preferable", I would suggest create a plunker with you problem and minimize the work required for other people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're leaving your page, I guess you have 2 ways of dealing wit it.
The first one could be to force your page to a location referent to an ID before leaving the page.

i.e: click -> location.href('#myItemId') -> location.href('externalResource').
http://jsfiddle.net/romulocollopy/gj2rss1v/6/

```
angular.module('myapp',[])
.controller("myCtrl",['$scope',function($scope){

    $scope.fruits = ['banana','aple','passion fruit', 'watermelon', 'spam','eggs'];

    $scope.link_to_fruit_detail = function(fruit){
        location.href = '#/fruit';
        location.href = 'http://www.'+fruit+'.com';
    }
}]);
```

other way is to store the y position of the click in a cookie:
http://jsfiddle.net/romulocollopy/gj2rss1v/7/

```
angular.module('myapp',['ngCookies'])
.controller("myCtrl",['$scope', '$cookieStore',function($scope, $cookieStore){
    if ( $cookieStore.get('y-click') ){
        var y = $cookieStore.get('y-click')
        window.scrollTo(y,0);
        console.log(y)
    }

    $scope.fruits = ['banana','aple','passion fruit', 'watermelon', 'spam','eggs'];

    $scope.link_to_fruit_detail = function($event, fruit){
        location.href = 'http://www'+fruit+'.com';
        $cookieStore.put('y-click', $event.y);
    }
}]);
```

booth have vantages and disadvantages, but I cannot think in a better way.